# Image of the upper half plane under a linear transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the image of $\{z:Im(z)>0\} $ under $f(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$?

Attempt:
I have evaluated $f$ at three points $0,-1,$ and $1$.

We have $f(0)=1$, $f(-1)=0$ and  $f(1)=\infty$. To me it seems the image should be the circle of radius $1$. But I feel like it is wrong since $i$ is in the plane $Im(z)>0$ and $f(i)=i$ not inside the circle of radius one. What I am I missing conceptually? How do I determine the image ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This map is a continuous bijection of the Riemann sphere with itself.

The image of the (extended) real line is the (extended) real line.

So the image of the upper half plane is the component of the complement of the real line containing $f(i)$.

So it is either the upper or the lower half plane. (Which is it?)

You will have to adjust the domain and/or range depending on whether you want to include $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Since $f(i)=i$ , and $i$ lies on the upper half plane , doesn't that mean that the image is the upper half plane? I just got little confused with "component of the complement" part of the answer.

Comment: Yes. The real line is mapped onto the real line (including the pt at infinity). So its complement is mapped onto the complement of the real line (same set again). In the domain, the complement has 2 components (upper and lower half planes). Their images are connected and must cover the complements in the image, so one must map onto the upper half plane and one onto the lower. Test a single point to see where it goes—the whole component must go there too, so the other component is mapped onto the other half plane in the image.

Comment: More geometrically, the sphere maps onto the sphere 1-1. The equator maps onto the equator, so the remaining hemispheres each map onto a remaining hemisphere.